# Using AJAX to make a call to the database

Tags: jquery

What I would like to do here is to use these functions but when the user clicks the element, I need to make a call to the database with the id that was clicked.

I have about 6 of these buttons that I would like to implement so how would I utilize one function to do this? I'm thinking to use one function that would take an id param

```
function toggle(id){
  //I'm lost from here. :)
}
```

Also, do I need an AJAX call on the enable and disable  toggles or can I use one call?

I'm not sure how any of this would be done. Can someone lend a hand?

```
  $(".enable").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.disable',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', true);
  });

  $(".disable").click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.enable',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', false);
  });
```

Comment: `$(element).on('click', function() { $.ajax({data: {id: this.id}}); })`

Comment: @adeneo, thanks. Do I put the enable and disable functions inside of what you've posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what kind of construction you are using, but a typical solution for the problem is calling a serverside script to retrieve the actual data from the database.

so client side you can call

```
function toggle(id)
{
     $.ajax({
         url: "database.php",
         data: { id: id },
         success: function(data) {
             // do something with the response
         }
     });
}
```

in this example the database.php file does the database information retrieval